# Jsp error when deploying on WebLogic 10.3 with IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, weblogic

I'm trying to reproduce a deployment setup for an EAR application.
Normally I use MyEclipse 10.7 to start the WebLogic 10.3.6 instance and run the application using the Autodeploy folder.
I'm trying to do the same thing using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 but I'm encountering a strange problem.

With MyEclipse everything works fine, but with IntelliJ, even if the application is correctly deployed (I can see it from the Admin console), I receive a HTTP 500 error from the main JSP page.

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "myVarName"
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:188)
    at jsp_servlet._app._path.__page._jsp__tag18(__page.java:1853)
    at jsp_servlet._app._path.__page._jspService(__page.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:327)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

What might be the cause of this discrepancy? This doesn't happen with MyEclipse.

Comment: Could you also post the relevant source code, and not just the error message?

Comment: That's a bit of a problem. I cannot post the source code! I know it would be helpful. Let me think what I can do

Comment: Not even a snippet? You'd hardly be jeopardising intellectual property with just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @SeverityOne I'm going to post a little bit of code. Need to organize it because I want to make clear how the app is organized.

Comment: Does it resemble this case? https://objectpartners.com/2012/01/03/jstl-core-set-tag-gotcha/

Comment: Guys, I found the problem... I was copying jar libraries under the WEB-INF/lib folder, which I shouldn't have done. They were overriding the correct JSTL library (and much more!). It was like two months ago I started trying migrating to IntelliJ. I'm exausted. Thank you nitind and SeverityOne for the patience